# localScroll and easing scrolling troubles

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-easing

I'm using localScroll and easing to smoothly scroll my site: http://www.pressedweb.com/beta

Everything is cool, but if the user tries to scroll before localScroll or easing are done doing their thing, it starts flickering and consistently tries to finish the animation.

Thanks a lot guys. StackOverflow is awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't figure this out, but I did remove the easing plugin/call and just set a duration and it seemed to run a lot more smoothly. So... not perfect, but at least it works somewhat.